# Xavier initialization in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow

I have built a simple ANN model:

```
#ANN:
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 128,activation = 'relu',input_shape = (784,)),#input layer
  tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),#batch normalization
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2), #dropout technique

  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 64,activation = 'relu'), #second fully connected layer
  tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),#batch normalization
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),#dropout technique

  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 10,activation = 'softmax') #output layer
    ])

model.compile(optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy']) #compiling the model


model.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size = 64,epochs = 100)
```

But I want to use Xavier initialization for weights but I didn't find how to do it in tensorflow 2.0

Answer (score 0):

In tf2.0, the [GlorotUniform](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/75a91fac16493b6f68c0740b214ff18f5d88e5a8/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py#L557) / [GlorotNormal](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/75a91fac16493b6f68c0740b214ff18f5d88e5a8/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py#L586) initializer , are also called Xavier uniform/normal initializer. So you can define a layer like this,

```py
model.add(Dense(64,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros'))
```